# I cannot install mssql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, archlinux

I cannot install mssql-server, because I have a newer version of `libldap-2.6.0-2`.

```
makepkg -sirc                                                      ✔ 
==> Making package: mssql-server 15.0.4188.2-3 (24 ينا, 2022 02:49:39 م)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
error: target not found: libldap<=2.4.59
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> libldap<=2.4.59
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
```

When I try to remove `libldap-2.6.0-2`. I got this error message:

```
:: removing libldap breaks dependency 'libldap' required by krb5
:: removing libldap breaks dependency 'libldap' required by lib32-libldap
:: removing libldap breaks dependency 'libldap' required by nfsidmap
:: removing libldap breaks dependency 'libldap' required by smbclient
:: removing libldap breaks dependency 'libldap' required by sudo
```

Comment: Hi Maybe you will have better luck at https://serverfault.com or https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have to install libldap24:
[Here is the Arch Linux User Repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libldap24)

Every time you have missing dependencies you can install them by yourself.

Comment: Mostafa tells us that he has libldap, but a version too high for mssql-server. Please read all of the question.

Comment: Do you mean that more than one version of libldap can coexist?
If yes, could you please explicit how to let mssql-server use the old version while the other dependees continue using the most recent one?